# banshee doesn't accept FLAC

Tags: 13.04, banshee, flac

1. banshee --> "Import Media"
2. "files" --->  selecting a song in .flac format
3. does *not* show up in banshee library.

Fails for multple different .flac files.  The .flac files play perfectly fine in other media players like VLC.

Everything works fine if in mp3 format.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 - raring

---

inspecting   `~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db`, it seems that the .flac files are in fact added to `banshee.db`, but they are not copied to the "music folder" as designated in banshee's preferences.  Also, although they appear in `banshee.db`, they do *not* show up in the Banshee GUI.

Comment: A file with the FLAC file extension is a Free Lossless Audio Codec file. try using VLC.

Comment: Do you have **libaudio-flac-decoder-perl** module installed anyway?

Comment: Yes @OluDoug , I know what FLAC is, thank you.  And I stated that it works fine in VLC.

I installed the library but it had no effect

Comment: Sorry about the misquote.